# making the logo in the center of the header

Tags: css

can you help me to make the logo in the center of the header

i tried a lot of time but i could not make it

this is the code i think you can make an editing on it

this the link of the site

https://almerrikhtoday.com/abdelbaset/london/

```css
.site-branding {
    float: left;
    padding: .3em 0 0;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    clear: right;
    font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 500;
    color: #333232;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: Include the relevant code in your post please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `margin: 0 auto;` to `.site-branding img`
and Remove `float: left;` from `.site-branding`

so the final code will be

```
.site-branding {
    padding: .3em 0 0;
}

.site-branding img{
    width: 500px !important;
    height: 80px !important;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.site-branding {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: .3em 0 0;
}
```

Don't use `float:left`.

Comment: that doesn't center it

Comment: the logo is center after remove float:left on the parent div

Comment: No it isn't. `.site-branding` is a normal `div` and does not have a width. left/right margin of `auto` only works if the element has a specified width that isn't 100% http://i.imgur.com/OypODsR.png

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting position to absolute and left to 50%. This will center the left side of the element. Using transform will center the middle of the element.

```
.site-branding {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: .3em 0 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0);
}
```